# How to check if string is BSON in C# .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bson

I have login method:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public ResponseBody<UserContext> Login([FromBody] RequestBody<Operator> userCredentials)
{}
```

`RequestBody` have `T Data` field.

is it possible to convert this method to be able to handle both JSON and BSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add BSON support to your API, this [artcile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/bson-support-in-web-api-21) should help. And based on request type API can supprort both JSON and BSON.

From article:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        // Other Web API configuration not shown...
    }
}
```

> Now if the client requests "application/bson", Web API will use the
>   BSON formatter.

Comment: I'am using AutoFac and i can't find where I can add bsonmediatypeformater or AddBsonSerializerFormatters.